# Global optimization

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, algorithms, stochastic-analysis, global-optimization

Assume that I want to find the global minimum of a non-linear, non-convex, multidimensional function subject to several restrictions.

Could you recommend me any deterministic strategy which can generally find an acceptable solution in a reasonable time-frame (say less than 1 hour)? Or should I go with the heuristic / stochastic route?

---

Ok, I will slightly rephrase the question:

If you had to find the global optimum of a multidimensional non-convex function, are there any type of problem/structure where deterministic strategies will be preferred to other stochastic/heuristic methods like [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) or a [genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm).

Comment: There's no method that can solve general non-convex large optimization problems efficiently.  It's necessary to know more about the structure of your problem.

Comment: How many variables and restrictions? Are the objective function and the restrictions given by explicit expressions?

Comment: @littleO, my question is of general nature. I would like to know if there are any deterministic methods which perform well in a broad class of non-convex functions. My impression is that most people use heuristic / stochastic algorithms for large non-convex problems, but I am not an expert in the subject

Comment: There are deterministic approaches to global optimization. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_optimization#Deterministic_methods.

Comment: This question is probably too broad.

Comment: @lhf, thank you for your answer. I am aware that deterministic method exists for global optimization. However, in my experience these methods are generally quite slow in reaching the global minimum. I just want to know if I may be missing something or if there is any particular method which performs well in general non-convex functions.